# Comparisons numbers syntax in 'if' (bash)

Tags: bash

```
if [ (( $year >= $3 )) ] && [ ((  $year <= $4 )) ]
```

Errors:

```
line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 11: `      if [ (( $year >= $3 )) ] && [ ((  $year <= $4 )) ] '
```

`$3` and `$4` are numbers, and `year` is a local variable and number too.

Whats the problem here? I can't get it.

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate, but the linked question is not the same.

Comment: What do you mean, @WilliamPursell ? Isn't it a duplicate to the one I mentioned? If so, I can reopen and you can reclose to a more-proper one.

Comment: The linked question provides the answers, and is probably fine.  At the time it seemed like this question was more specific, but perhaps this question should be rephrased more generally as in the linked duplicate.  No need to take any action.

Comment: thanks guys I solvd the problem using the link you posted.